# Disable / replace button when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I disable a button when a form is submitted or better still replace it with "processing your order please wait".

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could disable it with the [`$.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method,

```
$("input.myBtn").click(function(){
  $(this).attr( 'disabled', true ); 
});
```

or replace it with text with the [`$.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method.

```
$("input.myBtn").click(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith( '<p>Processing your order. Please wait.</p>' ); 
});
```

Comment: `replaceWith` is probably the best considering the OP request. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input:button').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$('#your-button-id').html('Please wait');
```